# How to keep text in anchor tag in the same position when border property is used

Tags: html, css, html-lists, anchor

I am planning to use Bootstrap's Scrollspy component to work on a `<ul>` element.

The issue for me is that when I use the `border-left` property on a `<li>` element, the text in the anchor tag gets shifted a little to the right.

What could I do to fix this?

Please see Pen:

https://codepen.io/AshNaz87/pen/QmVJVY

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.with-border {
  border-left: 3px solid grey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Fortune</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Favours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The</a></li>
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Brave</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @XYZ - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you're seeing this inconsistent offset of the text is because the border of an element actually take up physical space in the layout. To circumvent this, you will need to account for the space the border will take (see solution 1), or use alternative strategies that do not alter the flow of the document (see solution 2 and 3).

You can either use a:

1. transparent left-border on all your elements `<li>`,
2. `background-image` to visually mimic a border, or
3. abolustely positioned pseudo-element

---

## Solution 1: Transparent left border

This solution means introducing a transparent border on all `<li>` elements, and simply changing the `border-color` property when needed:

```
li {
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
}

li.with-border {
  border-color: grey;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li {
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

li.with-border {
  border-color: grey;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Fortune</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Favours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The</a></li>
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Brave</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## Solution 2: background-image to mimic border

Alternatively, you can use a linear gradient as a background image with a clearly demarcated border/breakpoint, to visually mimic a border:

```
li.with-border {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, grey 3%, transparent 3%);
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

li.with-border {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, grey 3%, transparent 3%);
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Fortune</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Favours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The</a></li>
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Brave</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## Solution 3: Absolutely-positioned pseudo-element

This solution is the most verbose one: it uses a generated pseudo-element that is absolutely positioned within the `<li>` element to visually mimic a border:

```
li {
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  display: none;
  content: '';
  background-color: grey;
}

li.with-border::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

li::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 3px;
  display: none;
  content: '';
  background-color: grey;
}

li.with-border::before {
  display: block;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Fortune</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Favours</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The</a></li>
    <li class="with-border"><a href="#">Brave</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @AshNaz87: Personally, solution 1 is the simplest and most grounded way to do it. It does have drawbacks though, e.g. if you want to animate border widths, then solution 2 is better. Solution 3 is more like "whoopie I am a pseudo element look at all the amazing things I can do" ;) if you want complex transformations to the border, then solution 3 is the only feasible one because you can treat it like any other HTML element.